# .Net C# regex for parsing URL parameters

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse a string, such as
**/a/b/c/d=uno/c=duo.html**

into three groups, such as

- **/a/b/c/**
- **d=uno/**
- **c=duo.html**

The parsing rules are:

1. The first group is everything until "d=" or the whole string if "d=" is not a part of the string.
2. The second group is everything until "c=" or the rest of the string following the first group if "c=" is not a part of the string.
3. The third group matches the rest of the string following the second group.

My problem with the following regex (?.+/)?(?d=([^/]+)/)?(?c=(?.*)) is that I don't know how to stop the  group when it encounters "d=".

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth would you change the URL parsing mechansim?  Can't you just accept the standard parsing method so you don't have to worry about something like this?  Or is this homework?

Answer (score 8):

Is the string you need to parse in the form you supplied, or is it an actual URL with parameters? If it's a URL, you can use [System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx) to extract a NameValueCollection containing each parameter and its value.

I've found this useful even in Windows Forms (eg parsing query parameters in ClickOnce deployed applications).

Comment: You can use the Uri class's Query property to extract the querystring from a Uri (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) and (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx)