# URLEncoding an Array of URLs .NET

Tags: .net, url, urlencode

I have an array with URLs like `http://www.example.com?a=1 1&b=2 2&c=3 3` and I need to URL Encode each of the URLs.

But if I use `HttpServerUtility.URLEncode(url)` it would output `http%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com%3fa%3d1+1%26b%3d2+2%26c%3d3+3`, but I need it to look like `http://www.example.com?a=1+1&b=2+2&c=3+3`

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Also the parameter values may not only have a space, they could have an & sign.

Comment: Are you trying to encode half of a string?

Comment: Whats wrong with the output for UrlEncode method?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your responses, you helped me come up with an solution I could use.

```
        Dim sURL As String = "http://www.example.com?a=1 1&b=2 2&c=3 3"
    Dim sURLParameters = sURL.Split("?")
    Dim parameters As NameValueCollection

    parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(sURLParameters(1))

    sURL = sURLParameters(0) & "?"
    For i As Integer = 0 To parameters.Count - 1
        sURL += parameters.Keys(i).ToString & "=" & Server.UrlEncode(parameters.Item(i).ToString)
    Next

    Response.Write(sURL)
```

This link lead me into the ParseQueryString solution.

[.Net C# regex for parsing URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434347/net-c-regex-for-parsing-url-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
string oldUrl = "http://www.example.com?a=1 1&b=2 2&c=3 3"
string oldUrlSplit = oldUrl.Split('?');
string newUrl = oldUrlSplit[0] + HttpUtility.URLEncode(oldUrlSplit[1]);
```

Obviously, you want to null check, etc.

**Edit:**

I was slightly short of the ball on this one. You will also want to split your oldUrlSplit[1] on `&` and subsequently on `=`, after which point you will only URLEncode the latter part (after the `=`). Thanks to @Anthony Pegram for pointing this out.

Comment: @Slaks: Nothing at all :-) I must be back in the stone age when only a character array could be passed into `Split`. Updating accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: This is incomplete. `=` would also be encoded, which would break the query string. Going further, subsequently splitting on `=` may also be invalid because it might very well be part of a value.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: Updated accordingly. Thank you for pointing out my shortcoming.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't going to be an out of the box method to do what you want to do.  From a programmatic perspective, an & in a QueryString is not something that it is going to be able to setup.

Also, UrlEncoding a URL is setting it up to be sent via a URL, this is why it is going to replace the / and other characters.

Sure you could urlEncode the querystring, but that will most likely cause un-intended results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the individual elements NOT the whole string so the URL you would end up with is http://www.example.com?a=1%201&b=2%202&c=3%203.

Can you see how the spaces within have been converted to %20 but it was only the actual variables "1 1" "2 2" "3 3" which are actually input into `HttpServerUtility.URLEncode()`

Like Mitchel says this isn't going to be an out of the box solution but you could so some fiddling in order to extract these variables for UrlEncoding.

Comment: do you know of a way I could parse through each URL parameter and Encode the value?

Comment: You *could* use a regular expression but I'm reluctant to recommend that as I believe there are almost certainly better methods